# DataBindingUtil type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm copying the code here;
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model#5

But I'm getting a type mismatch from the DataBindingUtil.inflate method. It's returning
ViewDataBinding!, when FragmentPlayBinding is expected.

I've downloaded the working app here https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps, and checked all dependencies etc. Everything looks good. Although that is an older project.

My code;

```
class PlayFragment : Fragment() {
private val TAG = "PlayFragment"
private lateinit var binding: FragmentPlayBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: PlayViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    //Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_play,
        container,
        false
    )
    Log.i(TAG, "Called ViewModelProvider.get")
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PlayViewModel::class.java)

    //viewBinding.correctButton.setOnClickListener { onCorrect() }
    //viewBinding.skipButton.setOnClickListener { onSkip() }
    //updateScoreText()
    //updateWordText()
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated")
}
```

}

Some things I've tried;

1. checked all dependencies. I've got the same as the working example project, but with the latest versions
2. cleaned and rebuilt project
3. invalidated and rebuilt caches
4. made sure all namespaces are all lowercase

I am using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Beta 3 (as I said, this code in example project works).

thanks

Comment: can you share your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Change this Line

from :

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_play,
        container,
        false
    )
```

to :

```
binding =  FragmentPlayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var binding = FragmentPlayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
//set variables in Binding
return binding.getRoot();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).